# set image as icon inside button reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a custom icon use image but not working

This is my code

```
button className="btn-play" style={btnplaylist}>
<i className="btnplaylist"></i>
</button>
```

This is css

```
.btnplaylist {
  background-image: url("../icon/playlist.png");
}

.btn-play {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2vh;
  outline: none;
}
.btn-play:hover {
  background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
}
```

This is the image

[image]

Can someone help me ? Thank you :)

Comment: *What* is not working for you? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello Ricky,**

I wasn't totally clear about your request, however I put together this snippet for you to use it as a guide on your own code. As you can see, I added some basic displaying rules to the CSS so that you could see your element on the screen.

Additionally, I have to mention that you need to check which folder you are using to render this note image(**relative or absolute urls**), since that could be an issue when rendering this in React. It is best to use a relative url to the root directory of your app.

For more information on Static content in React please visit [this link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/).

I certainly hope this can help with your case. Cheers and keep coding, it is the best thing in the world!

```js
// declare the functional component for the button
const CreateIconButton = props =>{
return (
<button className="btn-play">
<i className="btnplaylist"></i>
</button>
);
}

// Main component will be a class component
class RenderIconButton extends React.Component{
render(){
return(<div><CreateIconButton /></div>);
}; // End of Render
} // End of class component

// Let us render all in the root div on the DOM
ReactDOM.render(
<RenderIconButton />, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.btnplaylist {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD6k6.png");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display:block;
}

.btn-play {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2vh;
  outline: none;
}
.btn-play:hover {
  background-color:yellow;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!-- This is the root div to render all react content -->
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Glad to read this! I am glad to be of assistance!